# \addbibresource[location=remote] does not resolve cross-references

Tags: biblatex, biber

## Edit:

As per moewe's suggestion, the MWE is now truly minimal (I think). I removed the need for multiple `.bib` files by removing abbreviations, and made the main `.bib` file smaller (exactly as shown below).

Here's the log (`file.blg`):

```
[0] Config.pm:318> INFO - This is Biber 1.8
[0] Config.pm:321> INFO - Logfile is 'file.blg'
[60] biber-darwin:275> INFO - === Sat May 10, 2014, 14:45:31
[61] Biber.pm:333> INFO - Reading 'file.bcf'
[128] Biber.pm:630> INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
[156] Biber.pm:3053> INFO - Processing section 0
[181] Biber.pm:3190> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47261882/bibliography.bib' for section 0
[182] bibtex.pm:134> INFO - Data source 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47261882/bibliography.bib' is a remote BibTeX data source - fetching ...
[925] bibtex.pm:812> INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/var/folders/lw/xmh_g5vx4j9ctfxysb189qyr0000gn/T/ZegiE_xxWe/biber_remote_data_source_vqdu_.bib'
[930] bibtex.pm:134> INFO - Data source 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47261882/bibliography.bib' is a remote BibTeX data source - fetching ...
[1508] bibtex.pm:812> INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/var/folders/lw/xmh_g5vx4j9ctfxysb189qyr0000gn/T/ZegiE_xxWe/biber_remote_data_source_17lZd.bib'
[1509] Utils.pm:169> WARN - Duplicate entry key: 'a:watson:2014:01' in file '/var/folders/lw/xmh_g5vx4j9ctfxysb189qyr0000gn/T/ZegiE_xxWe/biber_remote_data_source_17lZd.bib', skipping ...
[1509] Utils.pm:169> WARN - Duplicate entry key: 'ic:bedau:2009:01' in file '/var/folders/lw/xmh_g5vx4j9ctfxysb189qyr0000gn/T/ZegiE_xxWe/biber_remote_data_source_17lZd.bib', skipping ...
[1509] Utils.pm:169> WARN - Duplicate entry key: 'c:barberousse:2009:01' in file '/var/folders/lw/xmh_g5vx4j9ctfxysb189qyr0000gn/T/ZegiE_xxWe/biber_remote_data_source_17lZd.bib', skipping ...
[1510] Utils.pm:169> WARN - I didn't find a database entry for crossref 'c:barberousse:2009:01' in entry 'ic:bedau:2009:01' - ignoring (section 0)
[1535] Biber.pm:2939> INFO - Overriding locale 'en_GB.UTF-8' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[1535] Biber.pm:2945> INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nty' keys
[1535] Biber.pm:2949> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_GB.UTF-8'
[1539] bbl.pm:482> INFO - Writing 'file.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
[1540] bbl.pm:555> INFO - Output to file.bbl
[1540] Biber.pm:105> INFO - WARNINGS: 4
```

It seems like the file is fetched twice (hence the warnings for duplicate keys). But I do not know how this is related to the issue.

---

When using `biblatex`'s (and `biber`'s) feature for fetching `.bib` files from remote locations, cross-refs are not resolved.

Consider the following bibliography file ([`bibliography.bib`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47261882/bibliography.bib)):

```
@Article{a:watson:2014:01,
  title           = {The Evolution of Phenotypic Correlations and ``Developmental Memory''},
  author          = {Watson, Richard A. and Wagner, G{\"u}nter P. and Pavlicev, Mihaela and Weinreich, Daniel M. and Mills, Rob},
  journal         = {Evolution},
  year            = {2014},
  month           = apr,
  volume          = {68},
  number          = {4},
  pages           = {1124--1138},
  doi             = {10.1111/evo.12337},
  url             = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/evo.12337},
}

@InCollection{ic:bedau:2009:01,
  title           = {The Evolution of Complexity},
  author          = {Bedau, Mark A.},
  pages           = {111--130},
  doi             = {10.1007/978-1-4020-9636-5_8},
  url             = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-9636-5_8},
  crossref        = {c:barberousse:2009:01},
}

@Collection{c:barberousse:2009:01,
  editor          = {Barberousse, Anouk and Morange, Michel and Pradeu, Thomas},
  title           = {Mapping the Future of Biology},
  booktitle       = {Mapping the Future of Biology},
  subtitle        = {Evolving Concepts and Theories},
  publisher       = {Springer Netherlands},
  year            = {2009},
  doi             = {10.1007/978-1-4020-9636-5},
  url             = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-9636-5},
  series          = {Boston Studies in the Philosophy of Science},
  volume          = {266},
}
```

If I cite `ic:bedau:2009:01` when using `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`, the cross-reference to `c:barberousse:2009:01` is resolved successfully. If I cite it when using `\addbibresource[location=remote]{<url>.bib}`, however, the cross-reference is not resolved, unless I happen to also cite `c:barberousse:2009:01` somewhere else in the text.

I am using an up-to-date version of `MacTeX` and compiling with `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex`.

Any ideas? Can someone at least confirm that they face the same issue? MWE below.

[image: Output]

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

% If I fetch the file from a remote location, cross-refs are not resolved.
\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47261882/bibliography.bib}
% If the file is stored locally, everything works okay.
% \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
% Does not resolve cross-reference.
\cite{a:watson:2014:01,ic:bedau:2009:01}.
% Resolves cross-reference because it is also cited explicitly.
% \cite{a:watson:2014:01,ic:bedau:2009:01,c:barberousse:2009:01}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE gives me the following error in the `blg`-file. Seems like an encoding problem, or the file is corrupt: _[11450] Utils.pm:169> WARN - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\Besitzer\AppData\Local\Temp\ogRl1vx8ui\biber_remote_data_source_Xu9Jt.bib_924.utf8, line 3, warning: 18 characters of junk seen at toplevel_

Comment: @musicman Those junk characters are headers I use to separate journal papers from conference papers etc -- they are a non-issue, really. I always get that warning, but the cross-referencing issue occurs only when I fetch the `.bib` file from a remote location.

Comment: I can replicate the issue here (`biblatex` 2.8, Biber 1.8, MikTeX 2.9). In the `.blg` file does not only complain about the junk characters, but also seems to skip a lot of duplicate entry keys even though the `.bib` file obviously do not contain any of those. It probably is an issue with how the data is fetched from remote locations. You might want to bring this up at [the `biblatex`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues) or [the Biber bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues).

Comment: Maybe you'd like to set up a truly minimal example with a stripped-down version of your `.bib` files containing just one or two entries that show the behaviour. (I think the `bib-abbrev.bib` file could easily be eliminated from the MWE; preferably a really minimal example would also not trigger other warnings anout junk chracters etc.) So the issue is easier to investigate.

Comment: @moewe As per your suggestion, I made the MWE, well, minimal. See my edited post please. The file I was linking to did contain those entries which were marked as duplicate – apologies for the confusion. But the duplicate entry warnings occur with the small bibliography file as well because, for some reason, it is downloaded twice (see the log) – no idea why and how it is related to the issue though. Let's see whether someone can figure this out before I submit a bug report. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the minimal example. When I wrote "even though the .bib file obviously do not contain any of those" above I meant to say "even though the .bib file obviously do not contain any of those *twice*". The duplication warnings do indeed seem to be related with Biber re-downloading the file; but I'm not sure whether this also causes the problem for the `crossref` entry or whether this is *because* of the `crossref`.

Comment: @moewe I see. Well, I went ahead and posted the issue on the `biblatex` bug tracker ([link](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/233)). Hopefully it'll help.

Comment: This was a bug and should be corrected in the biber 1.9 available in the DEV folder on SourceForge. You need to be using biblatex 2.9 DEV version with biber 1.9 (also on SourceForge).

Comment: @PLK That is great to hear! Could you write this as an answer so that I can accept it, please? Thanks a lot for your prompt reply!

Comment: Done, but please test it before accepting ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug and should be corrected in the biber 1.9 available in the DEV folder on SourceForge. You need to be using biblatex 2.9 DEV version with biber 1.9 (also on SourceForge). It was unnecessarily fetching remote sources more than once.

Comment: Just tested using `biber` 1.9 and `biblatex` 2.9. Everything works like a charm! Thanks for your help, and for your fantastic work on these two packages.