# How to create a remotely accessible, centralized .bib bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to create a remotely accessible, centralized `.bib` bibliography on GitHub that I can use in my `.Rnw` and `.tex` files in various directories. It would also make it easier to collaborate and decrease files in constant transit amongst collaborators. As an aside, I am more familiar with working with a GUI IDE like RStudio rather than the command line.

I tried Googling and found a few leads that didn't end up working. In particular, I found a guide on using submodules, but couldn't get it to work. I already tried `\bibliography{https://github.com/usernamehere/MyProjects.git/bibliography.bib}`, but this also did not work. Can someone please provide me with some new leads to explore?

**Update:**

Still can't get it to work. Taking the suggestions of Guido and Alan Munn in the comments below, I have tried a variation of the following MWE pseudocode (pseudo, because I omit my Git user name for anonymity). Am I making a mistake somewhere that prevents the citations from showing up?

** Temporarily left my GitHub username in place for a MWE **

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aw236/myrefs/master/myrefs.bib}

% Variations attempted that don't work:
% \addbibresource[location=remote]{https://github.com/aw236/myrefs/myrefs.bib}
% \addbibresource[location=remote,type=file]{https://github.com/aw236/myrefs/myrefs.bib}

\begin{document}
asdf.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using `\addbibresource[location=remote]{https:// etc.}`  The `\bibliography` command is deprecated in `biblatex`.

Comment: You should try with `\addbibresource[location=remote]{http:...}`. Also, there is a trailing `/` before `https`, and the manual specifies that only `ftp` and `http` protocols are supported.

Comment: @Guido Thanks. It appears that it also works with https though: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176325/addbibresourcelocation-remote-does-not-resolve-cross-references. I modified my post above with MWE (pseudocode to protect anonymity).

Comment: the `url` should point to a `bib` file. There is a `/` at the end.

Comment: @Guido Thanks. Removing the / does not solve the problem.

Comment: Your MWE works on my system (Biber 1.9, `biblatex` 2.9a, everything else up to date) even though I had to ait quite some time on the first Biber run. (Of course in your MWE no citations will show up at all - no matter if it worked or not, to check that add a `\printbibliography` at the end.) How does the "does not work" manifest itself - do you get an error, a warning, nothing shows up an empty `.bbl` file etc.? Please show us the `.blg` (Biber log file).

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your advice. Nothing shows up, even after adding a \printbibliography statement. Not sure what the explanation is, since I already have a \nocite{*} in the body of my code.

Comment: What did the `.blg` file say? Also try running Biber in debug mode (`biber --debug file`) and report your `.blg` findings.

Comment: Did you have any luck getting this to work? If not, please, give us more to work on: Biber's log output (the `.blg` file), have a look at the `.bbl` file (is it even created?).

Comment: Neither the .blg nor the .bbl files are created. Here's a link to the .Rnw filee I'm running in RStudio -- I think that may be the best way to resolve the root of this problem. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8yzivtxx4umy84/test.Rnw?dl=0

Comment: You do realise that the file you run (the one you linked to) is not the same as your MWE above, right? Because in your MWE you have the correct line `\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aw236/myrefs/master/myrefs.bib}`, while in your `.Rnw` file you run `\addbibresource[location=remote,type=file]{https://github.com/aw236/myrefs/myrefs.bib}` (the right solution is there, but commented out). Anyway, did you even run Biber on the file (normally at least a `.blg` is created even if something went wrong)? What is Biber's output on a manual run via the command line?

Comment: @moewe After posting my MWE, I tinkered with my .Rnw file. In my .Rnw file, the suggested line of code, `\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aw236/myrefs‌​/master/myrefs.bib}` didn't work, so I commented it out and iteratively tried a few other possibilities. Consequently, my linked .Rnw differs from the MWE. I'm not sure if I even run Biber, since I rely on the RStudio IDE which normally handles such things. I won't be able to further investigate the answers to your helpful troubleshooting questions until Saturday (too much homework right now). Thanks.

Comment: What about trying a normal TeX file first, that is take your above example as `.tex` file and compile it via the command line (`pdflatex test`, `biber test`, `pdflatex test`, `pdflatex test`, assuming that your MWE file is called `test.tex`). And check if that works, if it doesn't then the problem is with how RStudio invokes LaTeX/Biber etc.

Comment: A short search reveals that (at least in the past) RStudio has its problems with Biber. You will however have to run Biber to use the remote access fun. See [knitr and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71565/35864), the easiest way out is probably to configure RStudio to start `latexmk` or `arara`.

Comment: @moewe I'll investigate your helpful leads tomorrow afternoon and get back to you. My graduate program emphasizes use of RStudio and I think solving this problem can benefit my workflow and that of my classmates. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with Biber 2.1 (the current version), Biber 2.2 (beta) ([available from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/binaries/)) did  not have any problems in my test though, so I assume the problem was solved by updating some Perl components.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by a software update (running the MWE with Biber version 2.2 works perfectly fine).